# Im in a Udacity class: I was trying to configure my terminal and now this -bash: __git_ps1: command not found...?

Tags: terminal

I Have no clue on how to fix my terminal with this error:-bash: __git_ps1: command not found...
I am new and learning to code. I would greatly appreciate any help, I have looked at some other posts with answers to this question. I still cannot figure out how to fix mine. Im on a Mac OS Big Sur 11.4.? My git version is 2.31.1

Thanks

Comment: Did you recently uninstall `git`?

Comment: Actually I installed it, I am following an instructor in a class on Udacity. So l am fairly new to terminal. I don't want to screw anything up on my Mac. I just need to know exactly how to fix the-bash: __git_ps1: command not found issue. There are alot of threads on the issue, however I cant seem to find the fix. I would greatly appreciate any and all help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instruction carefully?
Instruction here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EXO5.jpg